# How to use a returned value in any function

Tags: bluej

This is quite a basic question
I am making a game where there will be two players.The game starts of at the main menu, where the players have an option of starting the game, entering player details, or quitting.

2 functions inputs the respective names of the two players (since a function can return only value) , and returns the two values to the main menu of the game, where the names are used throughout the game. This is my code so far:

```
import java.io.*;
class AQADO
{
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (isr);


    String Player1,Player2;
void main()throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------AQADO DICE GAME--------------------------------------------------------------\n\n\n");
    MainMenu();
}


void MainMenu()throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("Please enter your choice\n\n");
    System.out.println("1. Enter Player Names");
    System.out.println("2. Play Game");
    System.out.println("3. Quit\n");




    String MenuChoice = br.readLine();
    if(MenuChoice.equals("1"))
    {
        Player1Details();
        System.out.println("\nPlayer 1, you are called " + Player1 + "\n");
        Player2Details();
        System.out.println("\nPlayer 2, you are called " + Player2 + "\n\n");
        MainMenu();

    }
    else if (MenuChoice.equals("2"))
    {
        GameExe();
    }
    else if (MenuChoice.equals("3"))
    {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------THE END---------------------------------------------------------");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("\n\nSorry, couldn't get that.....\n\n");
        MainMenu();



    }
}

String Player1Details()throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("Player 1, please enter your name....\n");
    String Player1 = br.readLine();
    if (Player1.equals(""))
    {
        Player1 = "Player 1";
    }

    return Player1;


}

String Player2Details()throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("Player 2, please enter your name....\n");
    String Player2 = br.readLine();
    if (Player2.equals(""))
    {
        Player2 = "Player 2";
    }

    return Player2;




}
```

Could you help me, as both player names are getting returned as 'null'.

Answer (score 0):

You're not storing the values from `Player1Details()` or `Player2Details()` anywhere. Use the following.

```
Player1 = Player1Details();
Player2 = Player2Details();
```

You also may want to set`Player1` and `Player2` to `""` when you declare them to avoid any possible NullPointerExceptions.